# How do I Map through JSON array of object inside of array of objects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, api

here i am fetching data from API which is giving me response in "**array of objects**" i want to store it in the array called products and want to display it on the page.
Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import '../all.css';
import Axios from "axios";


const AllProduct = () => {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);


const fetchProducts = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(
     "http://localhost:8080/api/QueryAllProducts"

    );
    
  console.log(data.response);
  setProducts(data.response);
  console.log(products);
  
};

const display = () => {

  return (products ?? []).map(product => (
    <tr key={product.id}>
       <th>{product.id}</th>
       <th>{product.name}</th>
       <th>{product.area}</th>
       <th>{product.ownerName}</th>
       <th>{product.cost}</th>
     </tr>
   ) );
  
 }
useEffect(() => {
  fetchProducts();
}, []);


  return (
    
    <div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Owner Name</th>
      <th>Cost</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {display()}

  </tbody>
  
 
</table>
    </div>
  
  
  )
}

export default AllProduct;
```

I have used ReactJS for frontend and NodeJS

[here is the screenshot of what i am getting on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9nW2.png)

Comment: It could be useful to get the structure of the data you are receiving.

Comment: i have added one screenshot where you can see the data i am getting through API

Answer (score 1):

Check that the type of `products` is array. If it is an object, an error occurs.

Comment: response i am getting from api is array of objects and i want to map in products array

Comment: check `typeof data.response`. 
I think `data.response` is of type string.

Comment: yeah it's a string

Comment: and type of products is an object

Comment: You have to `JSON.parse` the data as string once. use `let parseData = JSON.parse(data.response)` and `setProducts(parseData)`.

Comment: it works, you are the best